# Getting data from database (mssql)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ssms

The project is written in .NET MVC technology. This is a specific page where the page shows articles that have certain categories. Based on the categories, I created filter that uses JavaScript / jQuery to filter the relevant articles according to the added class that each article has. The problem is that there is already code written in the background that gets a certain number of articles per page, and filter filters only those that are displayed on the page and not all of them. Could this be somehow solved with the help of JS or create some sort of query that would get correct articles from database?

This is piece of code that shows how categories are added in view:

```
  <span class="category @foreach (var cat in @item.Category) {@(cat.Title+" ")}">
         @foreach (var cat in @item.Category)
                                            {
        <span class="cat @cat.Title">@cat.Title</span>
                                            }
   </span>
```

This is code for getting the list of articles:

```
  var list = new List<ArticleViewModel>();
                foreach (var catalog in Model.Articles)
                {
                    list.Add(catalog);

                }
```

[image: Picture of the filter]

Code in controller for getting the articles:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int idContent, string idlang, bool isPreview, string type, int page = 1)
{
    ArticleIndexViewModel model = await GetIndexViewModel(idContent, idlang, type, page);
    
    return View(model);
}

private int _numPerPage = 4;

private async Task<ArticleIndexViewModel> GetIndexViewModel(int idContent, string idLang, string type, int page)
{
    ArticleIndexViewModel model = new ArticleIndexViewModel();
    model.Title = ContentViewModel.FromModel(await RepositoryService.ContentRepository.FindByIdAsync(idContent)).Title;



    model.CurrentPage = page;
    model.NumPerPage = await RepositoryService.ArticleRepository.CountAsync(p => p.Visible);
    model.Articles = (await RepositoryService.ArticleRepository.GetVisible(idLang, (page - 1) * _numPerPage, _numPerPage)).Select(ArticleViewModel.FromModel).ToArray();
    model.NumElements = await RepositoryService.ArticleRepository.CountAsync(p=>p.Visible);
    model.NumPerPage = _numPerPage;





    return model;
}
```

Comment: If I'm understating correctly, it looks like you probably want to modify the GetVisible method to not return the paginated data.

Comment: The getVisible is not the problem. Table column "Visible" has values 0 or 1. Based on that, the method already returns the correct article. The problem is in connection between the jQuery filter above and databse . Beacuse the filter only manipulates with the articles that it gets in single query. And that is 4, not all of them (200) .

Answer (score 0):

Go to controller/action associated with view and modify the Model. No you cant modify it with JQUERY or JS if there is no data in view.

P.S. It could be possible to fetch additional data from backend, only if you have an interface for it (controller/action which can serve you with this kind of data)

Comment: So I have to modify the model. The problem is that there is data in view, but the query gets ony 4 articles per page and the filter manipulates only with them.

I've updated the question with the controller code that gets the fixed number of articles.